# Foreach statement in listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, foreach

I have a problem with a foreach statement in my project. So far I have the code:

```
    foreach(object i in listboxFiles.Items)
    {
        if (i == ".ftpquota")
        {
            listboxFiles.Items.Remove(i);
        }
        if (i == ".")
        {
            listboxFiles.Items.Remove(i);
        }
        if (i == "..")
        {
            listboxFiles.Items.Remove(i);
        }
    }
```

I have this in a 1 second timer. It gets the item name all right, but when it gets to the `if` statements it says that they do not match, but they do?

Comment: Having this in a 1 sec. timer sounds like a lot of work … what for? Is this really necessary? it would be much better to execute this code *only* if the list actually changed (there are events for that!).

Comment: It's because there is a refresh button, but I suppose I could have it at the end of the button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing, you are changing a collection *while* iterating over it. This cannot work, so your code is fundamentally broken.

There are several ways to fix this; the simplest in your case would be to copy the items collection, iterating over the copy and changing (= removing from) the original:

```
var items = new System.Collections.ArrayList(listboxFiles.Items);

foreach (var item in items) {
    if (item.Equals("."))
        listboxFiles.Items.remove(item);
    …
}
```

Secondly, you are comparing an `object` to a `string`, hence the `==` operator does reference equality checking rather than testing for string equality. Either use `Equals` or do an appropriate cast.

Comment: Hey, I tried this but I am not getting the error of that I cannot convert an object to a bool. Also im getting 'Cannot assign to 'i' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

Comment: @Crazy: try again, using *my* code. You obviously did something differently because my code does *not* give these errors: I do not assign to the loop variable, and I do not convert to a boolean.

Comment: I tried this but I am getting back these errors: http://img38.yfrog.com/img38/6858/captureybe.jpg

Comment: Right, my bad. Try again using the updated code: it uses `ArrayList` instead of the generic `List<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

The equality check is not working because you should cast to string first and do an appropriate string comparison.

e.g.

```
if (string.Equals((string)i, ".ftpquota", StringComparison.Ordinal))
```

If you remove items from a collection of items whilst iterating through the collection, you may well run into trouble. One way to get around this problem is to start with the last item and count backwards, thus any removals you do will not affect the remaining items of the collection, e.g.

```
for(var i = listboxFiles.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    var item = listboxFiles[i];
    if (...)
    {
        listboxFiles.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```